# Python loop through two files, do computation, then output 3 files

Tags: python, file, loops

I have 2 tab delimited files
for example:

file1:

```
12  23  43  34
433  435  76  76
```

file2:

```
123  324  53  65
12  457  54  32
```

I would like to loop through these 2 files, comparing every line of file1 with file2 and vice versa.
If, for example, the 1st number of 1st line in file1 is the same as the 1st number of 2nd line in file 2:
   I would like to put from the 1st line in file1 in a file called output.
   then I would like to put all the lines from file1 that didn't find a match in file 2 in a  new file
   and all the lines from file2 that didn't find a match in file1 in a new file.

so far I have been able to find the matching lines and put them in a file but I'm having trouble putting the lines that didn't match into 2 separate files.

```
one=open(file1, 'r').readlines()
two=open(file2, 'r').readlines()
output=open('output.txt', 'w')
count=0
list1=[]    #list for lines in file1 that didn't find a match 
list2=[]    #list for lines in file2 that didn't find a match
for i in one:
    for j in two:
        columns1=i.strip().split('\t')
        num1=int(columns1[0])
        columns2=j.strip().split('\t')
        num2=int(columns2[0])
        if num1==num2:
           count+=1
           output.write(i+j)
        else:
           list1.append(i)        
           list2.append(j)
```

Problem I have here is with the else part.
Can someone show me the right and better way to do this, I would greatly appreciate.

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses everyone
The 3 output I would be looking for is:

Output_file1: #Matching results between the 2 files

> 12 23 43 34    #line from file1
>   12 457 54 32   #line from file2

Output_file2: #lines from the first file that didn't find a match

> 433 435 76 76

Output_file3: #lines from the second file that didn't find a match

> 123 324 53 65

Comment: First value from first row of the first file with first value from the second row of the second file?

Comment: To understand the logic of what you're trying to do, could you give the three output files you want for the two input files you've listed above?

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka:  Sorry for the confusion, what I was trying to say is that, in the example I gave, that is the condition or logic for defining a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that it is not the best way but it works for me and looks prety easy for understanding:

```
# Sorry but was not able to check code below
def get_diff(fileObj1, fileObj2):
    f1Diff = []
    f2Diff = []
    outputData = []
    # x is one row
    f1Data = set(x.strip() for x in fileObj1)
    f2Data = set(x.strip() for x in fileObj2)
    f1Column1 = set(x.split('\t')[0] for x in f1Data)
    f2Column1 = set(x.split('\t')[0] for x in f2Data)
    l1Col1Diff = f1Column1 ^ f2Column1
    l2Col1Diff = f2Column1 ^ f1Column1
    commonPart = f1Column1 & f2column1
    for line in f1Data.union(f2Data):
        lineKey = line.split('\t')[0]
        if lineKey in common:
            outputData.append(line)
        elif lineKey in l1ColDiff:
            f1Diff.append(line)
        elif lineKey in l2ColDiff:
            f2Diff.append(line)
    return outputData, f1Diff, f2Diff

outputData, file1Missed, file2Missed = get_diff(open(file1, 'r'), open(file2, 'r'))
```

Comment: Is there not a way to output all three files (outputData, file1Missed and file2Missed) at one time?

Comment: @user839145 i have modified my code to return all three lists at one time -mbut i was not able to check it. Do let me know if you have any problems with it

Comment: Thanks a lot Artsiom, I was hoping there would be a way to modified the last version of your code because I needed to do more comparison than just comparing the value alone. And I'm not very familiar with the set operation. I will study into it.

Comment: Set is not an operation it is a data type: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset . As for code - yes my prev version also can be modified, you can contact me and i will try to help.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use the csv module to read your files like so (you might have to mess around with the dialect, see http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html for help:

```
import csv
one = csv.reader(open(file1, 'r'), dialect='excell')
two = csv.reader(open(file2, 'r'), dialect='excell')
```

then you might find it easier to "zip" along the lines of both files at the same time like so (see http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
import itertools
file_match = open('match', 'w')
file_nomatch1 = open('nomatch1', 'w')
file_nomatch2 = open('nomatch2', 'w')
for i,j in itertools.izip_longest(one, two, fillvalue="-"):
    if i[0] == j[0]:
        file_match.write(str(i)+'\n')
    else:
        file_nomatch1.write(str(i)+'\n')
        file_nomatch2.write(str(j)+'\n') 
        # and maybe handle the case where one is "-"
```

I reread the post and realized you are looking for a match between ANY two lines in both files. Maybe someone will find the above code useful, but it wont solve your particular problem.

Comment: Thank Pat, I have found this example and yes it only searches linewise but thanks anyways.

Comment: Rather than "messing with the dialect" (I don't believe there's such a dialect as `'excell'`, by the way; it'd be `'excel'`), he could simply use `delimiter='\t'`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [set operation](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#set-objects)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parse(filename):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for line in open(filename):
        # take the first number and put it in result
        num = int(line.strip().split(' ')[0])
        result[num].append(line)  
    return result

def select(selected, items):
    result = []
    for s in selected:
        result.extend(items[s])
    return result

one = parse('one.txt')
two = parse('two.txt')
one_s = set(one)
two_s = set(two)
intersection = one_s & two_s
one_only = one_s - two_s
two_only = two_s - one_s

one_two = defaultdict(list)
for e in one: one_two[e].extend(one[e])
for e in two: one_two[e].extend(two[e])

open('intersection.txt', 'w').writelines(select(intersection, one_two))
open('one_only.txt', 'w').writelines(select(one_only, one))
open('two_only.txt', 'w').writelines(select(two_only, two))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this code fits your purposes

```
one=open(file1, 'r').readlines()
two=open(file2, 'r').readlines()
output=open('output.txt', 'w')

first = {x.split('\t')[0] for x in one}
second = {x.split('\t')[0] for x in two}
common = first.intersection( second )
list1 = filter( lambda x: not x.split('\t')[0] in common, one )
list2 = filter( lambda x: not x.split('\t')[0] in common, two )
res1 = filter( lambda x: x.split('\t')[0] in common, one )
res2 = filter( lambda x: x.split('\t')[0] in common, two )
count = len( res1 )
for x in range(count):
    output.write( res1[x] )
    output.write( res2[x] )
```